Issue with AusweisApp in Safari - Mixed content problem when connecting to a local server - HTTPS site with JS opening http://127.0.0.1:24727
Question:
Hello! I'm working with a program called AusweisApp, which is distributed through government services for working with ID cards. The app acts as a server on the local host and awaits data from our authentication website.
We have a script, eid.js, which first determines if the user is on a smartphone or a PC/Mac.
If it's a PC/Mac, it checks if the AusweisApp client is running on that machine.
If it's running, the script redirects to the local AusweisApp server.
This mechanism works on Windows and partially on macOS (in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox), but in Safari, an error occurs where the browser cannot open the address of the local server.
It seems like the issue is due to "mixed content" because our page is opened via HTTPS, while the local server is running on HTTP.
eid.js
`
this.openURL = function (url) {
// it can take a while for the dialog to appear
// gives user time to allow open the app before they are forwarded to the app store.
const dialogTimeout = 5000;
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (!didHide && options.onIgnored) {
      options.onIgnored();
    }
  }, dialogTimeout);

  window.location = url;
}; 

`
We have examples of websites where this technology is successfully implemented:
Arbeitsamt.de
id.bund.de
Can anyone help me understand how this issue is solved on these sites so that we can adapt it for our project? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Links:
Wikipedia page on AusweisApp
Official AusweisApp website
We expected the redirection to work seamlessly across all browsers.
It seems like the issue is due to "mixed content" because our page is opened via HTTPS, while the local server is running on HTTP.

Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting .

with my current knowledge, I can tell you that some browsers don't allow connection to non-secured servers, as a http or a websocket one.
So I assume the only way to get it working on all browsers is to get a (free) ssl certificate via certbot and let's encrypt.
if you don't want to bother, there is a website called zerossl that allow you to get a free ssl certificate for 1 month.
Hope this helped.

Thank you for your response. I appreciate your suggestion. However, our challenge lies specifically with Safari's handling of mixed content when redirecting to the local server on http://127.0.0.1:24727.
We are aware of two websites, Arbeitsamt and idbund.de, which have successfully implemented this technology and managed to resolve this issue in Safari. Given this, we are seeking a similar solution that addresses our specific requirements.
If anyone has insights or experience with achieving this in Safari, especially with a local server, it would be greatly appreciated.
